# Random bouncing balls in flash AS3 *Updated*

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

UPDATE

I now have this but only one ball bounces when the flash movie is run

```
var array:Array = new Array;

var dx:Number = Math.random() * 20;

var dy:Number = Math.random() * 10;

var velX:Number = 5;

var velY:Number = 5;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movearray);


for (var i:Number = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    var ball:Ball = new Ball();

    ball.x = Math.random() * 550;

    ball.y = Math.random() * 400;

    addChild(ball);

    array.push(ball);

}


function movearray(evt:Event):void {

    ball.x += velX;

    ball.y += velY;

    if (ball.x > stage.stageWidth - ball.width / 2 || ball.x < 0 + ball.width /2){
      velX *= -1;
    }
    else if (ball.y > stage.stageHeight - ball.height / 2 || ball.y < 0 + ball.height /2){
      velY *= -1;
   }
}
```

Thanks any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course only one ball moves, that's because in your `movearray` function you are only referring to one ball instance. Since you are storing are your ball instances in an array, you have to loop through that array to check for **every** ball. Also, since each ball moves independently, is mandatory to store an array of ball velocities as well.

For example:

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var numBalls:uint = 20;
var arrayBalls:Array = new Array();
var arrayVels:Array = new Array();

//I don't know what is this for
//var dx:Number = Math.random() * 20;
//var dy:Number = Math.random() * 10;

var initialVelX:Number = 5;
var initialVelY:Number = 5;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movearray);

for (var i:uint = 0; i < numBalls; i++)
{

    var ball:Ball = new Ball();

    ball.x = Math.random() * 550;
    ball.y = Math.random() * 400;

    addChild(ball);

    arrayBalls.push(ball);

    //use a Point to store velocities in two axis
    //you could also set random starting velocities
    //so each ball would move differently initially
    var vel:Point = new Point(initialVelX,initialVelY);

    arrayVels.push(vel);

}

function movearray(evt:Event):void 
{
    var ball:Ball;
    var vel:Point;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < numBalls; i++)
    {

        ball = arrayBalls[i];
        vel = arrayVels[i];

        ball.x += vel.x;
        ball.y += vel.y;

        if (ball.x > stage.stageWidth - ball.width / 2 || ball.x < 0 + ball.width /2)
        {
            vel.x *= -1;
        }
        else if (ball.y > stage.stageHeight - ball.height / 2 || ball.y < 0 + ball.height /2)
        {
            vel.y *= -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks and the bit u did not know was for another thing i had working where the balls move from left to right and go down.... like space invaders

Answer (score 0):

To move a ball you need to specify velocity for it. Suppose a ball has velocity vx, vy. And the time between successive call of `movearray` is dt. So the new position of the ball is:

```
dx = vx * dt;
dy = vy * dt;
xNew = xOld + dx;
yNew = nOld + dy;
```

When a ball hits top or bottom part of the screen you need to negate vy. When ball hits left or right end you need to negate vx. For example, vx is positive and thus the ball is moving right. When it hits the right end you need to make `vx = -vx`, so vx is now negative and the ball will start moving left.

So you have to store velocity (may be random, just like the initial positions) for every ball and inside `movearray` calculate dt and new positions. And if any ball hits the wall then negate the velocity accordingly. To test the hit on wall you need to compare their x, y coordinates with screen width, height etc. To calculate dt you can keep track of calling time of `movearray`.

```
dt = currentTime - lastTimeCalled;
lastTimeCalled = currentTime;
```

Note that, this method will only collide on screen boundary, it won't detect ball-ball collision.

Comment: yeah i forgot to say im a complete noob, and i dont really understand that :(

Comment: You don't know the basic high school physics like `dx = vx * dt; x += dx`? In that case I am afraid that I won't be able to make an easier explanation :-(

Comment: After a little bit googling I found this: http://www.flashguide.org/Flash/Make-a-bouncing-ball-with-Flash.html. Please check the code in step5. That might help.

Comment: Thanks, are u able to help me now ??

Comment: You just need to do that for all balls in array. Also you can set different velX, velY for every ball, i.e. store the velX, velY in an array just like balls array so that different balls move in different directions. Also the last `else if` should be two different `if`. Otherwise if the ball hits corner then only velX will change, not velY.