# AS3: TypeError: Error #1009 with interactive application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, interactive

I am creating an interactive application that allows the user to create circles that collide against circles of different colours to produce sounds determined by their size. Using code referenced from a previous question here and an AS3 game tutorial, I got the basis of what I wanted to work, however Flash keeps spewing out this error constantly while it runs:

*TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at proto_fla::MainTimeline/movearray()*

Messing about with the code doesn't get rid of the error, and frankly I'm getting stuck. I know the for loop from the example got rid of it, but it isn't what I'm aiming for since it releases multiple balls at a time, rather than one.

Here is the code so far:

```
    /*references code from 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953891/random-bouncing-balls-in-flash-as3-updated
    http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-brick-breaker-game-in-as3-part-2/
    */
    var j;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    var initialVelX = Math.random() * 5; //initial X velocity for each ball
    var initialVelY = Math.random() * 5; //initial X velocity for each ball
    var numBalls=100;
    var arrayBalls:Array = new Array(); //makes array to put balls in
    var arrayVels:Array = new Array(); //makes array for each ball's velocities

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBall);

    var count = 0;


    function addBall(e:MouseEvent):void {

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movearray);       

            var initialVelX = Math.random() * 5; //initial X velocity for each ball
            var initialVelY = Math.random() * 5; //initial X velocity for each ball

            var ball:Ball = new Ball();

            ball.x = mouseX; //places ball on a random part of the stage
            ball.y = mouseY; //places ball on a random part of the stage
            addChild(ball); //creates a ball

            arrayBalls.push(ball); //puts ball into array

            var vel:Point = new Point(initialVelX,initialVelY); //creates a point determined by the velocity of ball's X and Y speed

            arrayVels.push(vel); //pushes velocities of balls into array
        }




    function movearray(e:Event):void 
    {
        var ball:Ball;
        var vel:Point;

        for (var j:uint = 0; j < numBalls; j++)
        {

            ball = arrayBalls[j]; //equates ball variable to balls stored in array
            vel = arrayVels[j]; //equates velocity variable to velocities stored in array

            ball.x += vel.x; //speed of ball determined by vel variable
            ball.y += vel.y; //speed of ball determined by vel variable

            if(ball.x >= stage.stageWidth-ball.width){
                vel.x *= -1;
            }
            if(ball.x <= 0){
                vel.x *= -1;
            }
            if(ball.y >= stage.stageHeight-ball.height){
                vel.y *= -1;
            }
            if(ball.y <= 0){
                vel.y *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing seems wrong, but what happens a lot in programming is that other code form another part of your program has an error, but it shows itself in other parts. Here, there is nothing wrong with you're code excerpt so it must be another part. Try using the build in debugger, it is a hell of a lot easier to debug code than trace statements or following logic yourself. If you take the time to learn it, trust me it is worthwhile, and I am sure it could solve this problem for you in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the movearray() method, you are looping from 0 to `numBalls` (which is set to 100). When this runs, 100 balls haven't yet been created.

So, the error is Flash telling you that you are trying to change properties (`ball.x += vel.x;`) of an object that doesn't exist.

To fix this, try changing your for loop in movearray() to this:

```
for (var j:uint = 0; j < arrayBalls.length; j++)
```

This will only loop through the number of ball objects that exist in the `arrayBalls` array.

Comment: A quick and dirty way to help get to the bottom of these run-time errors is to (a) locate the function name that the error message gives you, (b) put different trace statements throughout the problematic function, and (c) run it to see which is the last trace statement before the error message comes up.

Comment: If you use break points instead, you don't have to go back and remove the trace statements.